# Grails REST update of collection property on Resource annotated Domain not working

Tags: rest, grails, controller

I'm having a very weird problem with `@Resource` annotated Domain classes and the automatically generated `RestfulController` for said classes. Specifically, my Domain entity `Product` has a Collection `hasMany` property `parts` within of type `Part`, and I'm trying to use PUT to update `parts` within a `Product` instance and the update is not working.

My containing Domain entity is `Product` which is defined as follows:

```
package com.test

import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri='/rest/product', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Product
{
  Integer completed  // Completed quantity
  Set<Part> parts    // Each requested product has a list of requested parts

  static hasMany = [parts: Part]

  static constraints = {
    parts minSize: 1
  }
}
```

and my Part definition is as follows:

```
package com.test

import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri='/rest/part', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Part
{
  String identifier // Each part must have an identifier
  Double weight     // How much does each unit of this product part weigh
  Product product   // The product request that this part request belongs to

  static belongsTo = [product: Product]

  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

In my BootStrap.groovy I already created two parts each for two products (so 4 parts in total).

```
package broken.put.array.property

import com.test.Product
import com.test.Part

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
      Product product = Product.findOrSaveWhere(completed: 4)
      product.addToParts(new Part(product: product, weight: 1237, identifier: "part1").save(failOnError: true, flush: true))
      product.addToParts(new Part(product: product, weight: 1236, identifier: "part2").save(failOnError: true, flush: true))
      product.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
      Product product2 = Product.findOrSaveWhere(completed: 3)
      product2.addToParts(new Part(product: product2, weight: 1235, identifier: "part3").save(failOnError: true, flush: true))
      product2.addToParts(new Part(product: product2, weight: 1234, identifier: "part4").save(failOnError: true, flush: true))
      product2.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

So after running the app I do the following:

```
$ curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/product/1" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"parts" : [{ "id": 1 }], "completed": 3}'
```

to update the `parts` Collection property of the `Product` with ID 1 from having 2 parts to having 1 part. For some reason, the update always ends up not really modifying the parts property at all, as seen in the response JSON:

```
{"id":1,"parts":[{"id":2},{"id":1}],"completed":3}
```

So I decided to debug this by making my `@Resource` annotation include a `superClass` attribute that points to my own Controller where I can do some `println`. I copied the body of the `update()` method from the default RestfulController and sprinkled println statements in it to find out where the problem could be. After some experimentation, I learned that after setting `instance.properties` to `getObjectToBind()`, the `parts` Collection within still has the old values (Part objects with both ID 1 and 2), instead of what I had sent in the JSON body of the PUT (a single Part object with ID 1).

But I found something else very surprising, if I placed a `println` statement printing out the `instance.properties` BEFORE the line where it is set to `getObjectToBind()`, the `PUT` update suddenly works with my intended behavior. Anything other than that location won't do. And it has to be printing the contents of `instance.properties`.

As I realize this is bordering on voodoo, I've created an isolated test case project in the form of a zip file that I've uploaded to [TinyUpload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=52412497726791498120&t=5241249772679149812034574). My grails version is 3.3.6. Would love to hear from anyone who has ever seen this, or who can help me understand why this is happening. All you need to do is unzip the zip file into a folder and run it using grails dev run-app. The current state of the code has that `println` line (line 42) commented out in `src/main/groovy/com/test/ReactAdminRestfulController.groovy` so you can see what I have described above. But uncommenting that line and re-running the app will give the correct behavior.